# pandas fill null values by the mean of that category

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have this dataset. You can see there's a `null Value` for the `Product` `Wheat`. I want to fill this null `Value` by the mean of the category of that product. So for wheat this is category `A` which have mean `5+8/2=6.5`.

```
  Product     Value Category
0   Rice        5      A
1   Corn        8      A
2   Milk       17      B
3   Wheat      NaN     A
4   Ice cream   3      B
```

Here's what I have tried.

```
df[Value].fillna(df.groupby('Category')[Value].mean(),inplace=True)
```

But this is not working. As it returns means of each category. So how can I achieve this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` + `transform` to fill `NaN` values with groupwise means.

```
df['value'] = df['value'].fillna(df.groupby('Category')['value'].transform('mean'))
df['value'] = df['value'].fillna(df['value'].mean())
df
```

Comment: Why are there two separate computations for the mean?

Comment: I guess he showed two ways to fix the null values by mean. @sammywemmy

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df['Value'] = df.groupby('Category')['Value'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  product = row['product']
  value = row['value']
  category = row['category']
  if np.isnan(value):
    category_mean = df.groupby('category')['value'].mean()[category]
    print(f'category_mean : {category_mean}')
    df.loc[index, 'value'] = category_mean
  else:
    print(product, value, category)
```

[image]

https://github.com/biranchi2018/My_ML_Examples/blob/master/16.Stackoverflow_Pandas.ipynb

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works but seems little complex. Although learnt a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```py
data1 = data.groupby('Category')['Value'].mean().reset_index()
data1.columns = ['Category','Mean']
data = data.join(data1.set_index('Category'), on='Category')
data['Value'] = data['Value'].fillna(data['Mean'])
data=data.drop('Mean',axis=1)
data
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXi6z.png)